# Array List Binary Search in Java

Tags: java

I have a programming assignment that needs a contains method that overrides the original arrraylist contains method. The method should check if the list is sorted, and then perform a binary search on the arraylist for the key. If the arraylist isn't sorted, then it should just preform the original contains method from arraylist. Here's my code right now.

```
public void contains(String key) {
    System.out.println("Initializing");
    if(isSorted()) {
        int first = 0;
        int last = this.size() - 1;
        while(last >= first) {
            int mid = (first + last) / 2;
            if (this.get(mid).equals(key)) {
                System.out.println(this.get(mid));
            }
            if (this.get(mid).compareTo(key) == 1) {
                System.out.println(this.get(mid));
                first = mid + 1;
            }
            if (this.get(mid).compareTo(key) == -1) {
                System.out.println(this.get(mid));
                last = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Character does not exist");
    }
}
```

I get no errors when I run it, however when I try to preform the search nothing happens.

Comment: Your method does not override `ArrayList.contains()`.  It has the wrong argument type.  And this is why it is permitted to have the wrong return type.

Comment: It would be helpful if you presented at least the class declaration for the class containing this method.

Comment: Surely you've got to go through the entire list to check if it's sorted anyway; so you may as well check contains while you're doing that.

Comment: You're quite right, @AndyTurner, but I'm supposing that the problem is an academic exercise that is focused more on teaching binary search than on producing an efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Bollinger stated in the comments. Your method does not override the `contains()` method, so your implementation of the method does not get called at all.

Your method should match the signature of the `contains()` method defined the `List` interface, so that is actually overrides the implementation of the `ArrayList` class.

So your method should be like this:

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // your logic goes here
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that your method does nothing if your the array is not sorted, which is not what it should do as you described the question. To use the default implementation of the `contains` method in the `ArrayList` you can write:

```
        if (sorted)
            // do binary search
        else
            return super.contains(key);
```